# How to prevent inserted currency sign if value is 0?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I want to ask is there a way to prevent dollar sign to be inserted if the value is 0?

I am using string function `Format` to make currency sign  `@string.Format("{0:C}",0))` update my output is $0.00

Comment: To clarify: you want 0 to be formatted differently (for example `0`) than other numbers, which you want to show as currency?

Comment: if the value is 0 don;t format as currency just 0.00 without $ sign

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a three-part custom format string with `;` separating the different sections.  The first section describes the format applied to positive numbers; the second applies to negative numbers; and the third applies to zero:

```
const string format = "{0:$#,0.00;-$#,0.00;0.00}";

string.Format(format, 1.23d) // =>  $1.23
string.Format(format, -1.23d) // => -$1.23
string.Format(format, 0d) // => 0.00
```

Sadly, this only works with custom formats, meaning you cannot use built-in specifiers like `C` in the individual sections.  One consequence of this is that you cannot rely on the system choosing which currency symbol to include based on the thread culture; you must include it directly in the format string.

Answer (score 4):

Make an extension method to do this:

```
public static string ToCurrency(this int value)
{
   return value == 0 ? value.ToString("N2") : value.ToString("C");
}
```